# Console.WriteLine conversion to string

Tags: winforms, console-application

In Csharp its normal to write to the console like below, i am translating an old console app to a gui based application and now i wonder if this can be turned simply in strings; so i can do a quick rename, of console.Writeline

```
    var p = new { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates" };

    Console.WriteLine("Fristname {0} Lastname {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName);
```

I want something like that, i'll like to keep using that format, but turn it to a normal string
so you get

```
     tbTextBox1.text = tbTextBox1.text + ("Fristname {0} Lastname {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
```

Is there a simple string conversion function for that ?

I know i could write it like below but if there is a simple conversion i would prefer that

```
     tbTextbox1.text= "Firstname " + p.Firstname + " Lastname " + p.lastname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
tbTextBox1.text += String.Format("Fristname {0} Lastname {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `String.Format()`, which does exactly that.